# Filter channel entries by slug

Tags: templating, entries, sections

Is there any way to output the content of a channel entry by their slug?

For example, say I have an asset field called "image" in each channel entry, I want to output the content of that field only for the channel entry filtered by the slug "home", I've tried both:

```
{% for item in craft.entries.section('images').slug('home') %}
    {{ item.image.first() }}
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% for item in craft.entries.section('images').find().slug('home') %}
    {{ item.image.first() }}
{% endfor %}
```

but neither work...

Comment: By "images" do you mean entries or asset-fields inside entries? Also your code looks correct, can you post a bit more of it?

Comment: Hi Victor, I've edited the question to clarify what I mean. In short, say I have an asset field called "image" in each channel entry, I want to output the content of that field *only* for the channel entry filtered by the slug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example won't work since `.find()` should be at the end of the [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel). But since you treat the CriteriaModel like an array, you don't [need to add it at all](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#outputting-elements).

Your first code looks correct, but you should [check if the loop found an entry](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-else-clause):

```twig
{% for item in craft.entries.section('images').slug('home') %}
    ....
{% else %}
    No entry found
{% endfor %}
```

Also your current code is only outputting the title of the [AssetFileModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel):

> Outputting an AssetFileModel object without attaching a property or
>   method will return the asset’s Title

That's why you should add the "url" property, and also check whether the field contains an asset:

```twig
{% for item in craft.entries.section('images').slug('home') %}
    {% set asset = item.image.first() %}

    {% if asset %}
       {{ asset.url }}
    {% else %}
        No asset added to the field
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    No entry found
{% endfor %}
```